# The default ActiveAdmin filter doesn't filter my index table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filter, activeadmin

I have an application where you can fill in metadata of documents. I currently have a problem with the default filtering as it doesn't filter my index table. The filter options are shown on the right side and you can also see the filtering options in the url and params after you choose a filter and hit the button.

```
utf8=✓&q%5Buser_id_eq%5D=3&commit=Filter&order=id_desc
```

But somehow the index table doesn't refresh.

The only scope I have is the default:

```
  scope :all, default: true
```

**EDIT**

I think it has something to do with the pagination because If i remove pagination the filters work again.

This is my current index method in my app/admin/DocumentType.rb file:

```
def index
  index! do |format|
    @document_types = DocumentType.where(archived_at: nil).page(params[:page])
    file_name = "document_types_#{DateTime.now.strftime('%a_%d_%b_%Y_%H%M%S').downcase}"

    format.xls {
      spreadsheet = DocumentTypesSpreadsheet.new @document_types
      send_data spreadsheet.generate_xls, filename: file_name + ".xls"
    }
  end
end
```

Only document types which are not archived should be displayed in the index therefore i have

```
@document_types = DocumentType.where(archived_at: nil).page(params[:page])
```

Now with this my filter don't work. But if I remove this line completely they work again except now it displays also the archived document types. And if I remove the `.page(params[:page])` part I get the following error message:

```
 Collection is not a paginated scope. Set collection.page(params[:page]).per(10) before calling :paginated_collection.
```

Comment: plz show your code. is 'user' belongs_to association or has_many?

Comment: @NeverBe please take a look at my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your controller with this

```
def index
  index! do |format|
    @document_types = DocumentType.where(archived_at: nil).ransack(params[:q]).result
    file_name = "document_types_#{DateTime.now.strftime('%a_%d_%b_%Y_%H%M%S').downcase}"

    format.xls {
      spreadsheet = DocumentTypesSpreadsheet.new @document_types
      send_data spreadsheet.generate_xls, filename: file_name + ".xls"
    }
  end
end
```

But you need to be sure, you deisplay the records with this condition as well:

```
.where(archived_at: nil)
```

because the exported result will be different with displayed